# Does elmahr supports console application?

Tags: console, elmah, elmahr

I am using elmahr for my web application. I want to extend it to my batches and console application. Do we have any direct references for the same? Thanks in Advance

Regards
Amal Thomas

Answer (score 0):

ElmahR does not support that out of the box, but there is a fork that implements something very similar to what you did:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16139769/720780

From there you could probably extract what you need. I never tried it personally but the idea is very promising, so I'd advise you have a look.